Using PD4ML not able to render few Chinese characters in PDF
I am trying to generate the PDF using PD4ML but while rendering it few Chinese characters are appearing as ? in output file.
Below is code snippet for reference through which I am generating PDF.
try {
            // Initialize PD4ML
            PD4ML pd4ml = new PD4ML();

            // Set page size and orientation (A4, landscape mode)
            pd4ml.setPageSize(PD4Constants.A4);
            pd4ml.changePageOrientation(PD4Constants.A4);
            pd4ml.useTTF("java:fonts", true);
            pd4ml.enableDebugInfo();
            // Set PDF output stream
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\output.pdf");

            // Define the HTML content (static)
            String htmlContent = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">  <meta charset=\"utf-8\"> <html><body>䁱         需要创建中文PDF</body></html>";

            // Convert HTML content to PDF
            pd4ml.render(new StringReader(htmlContent), fos);

            // Close output stream
            fos.close();

            System.out.println("PDF generated successfully.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Below mentioned characters are causing issue.
䁱
Went through below question in community
PD4ML issue while converting an HTML that contains Chinese characters
I already have simsun.ttf present in my fonts.jar
Can someone help with this issue?

I have tried adding SimSun-extb in my fonts.jar but it did not help as it was not loaded in while generating the PDF. Sharing pd4fonts.properties entry for said ttf below
simsun\ ext \b=simsun-ext-b.ttf
Any pointer on this, how to get it loaded?

I suspect your code is missing a configuration. The SimSun-ExtB font needs to be set as a fallback font for extended characters. Can you try to set it like below?
pd4ml.setDefaultTTFs("SimSun", "SimSun-ExtB");

Alternatively, if the issue still cannot be resolved, you can try using third-party API services like PageSnap.co and worry less about the rendering.
